# На заході України чи на Західній Україні?

Tags: словосполучення

Останнім часом у публічному просторі почастішали заклики не вживати вирази `Західна Україна`, `Східна Україна`, пояснюючи це тим, що подібні вирази є ознакою сепаратизму та розділення жителів країни за територіальною ознакою. Натомість пропонується використання `на сході України` та `на заході України`.

Ми можемо знайти різні приклади вживання, зокрема `Східна/Західна Німеччина`, `Східний/Західний Єрусалим`, які дійсно були/є розділені, `Північна Ірландія`, `Західна Сахара`, де `Північна/Західна` є частинами назв країни. Є ще `Східна/Західна` Європа.

На мій погляд, сепаратизм у виразах на кшталт `Західна Україна` є перебільшенням, однак хочу дізнатись думку спільноти.

Comment: Не думаю, що американці закладають сепаратизм у це поняття [Western United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_United_States).

Comment: @sashaeve, Ваше запитання про Україну. Отже, будьте ласкаві наводити приклади саме щодо вжитку "Західна Україна", "захід України" і т.д. Або переформулюйте запитання, якщо цікавлять правила вжитку власних назв.

Comment: @Sutnôstj Поясніть, будь ласка, як саме я підтвердив думку про сепаратизм. Зважайте на *Western United States (also called the American West, the Far West, and the West)*.

Comment: @Sutnôstj Як те, що американці розрізняють _West_ і _Western_ разом з моїм коментарем підтверджує думку сепаратизму?

Comment: @Yola Схоже, таки не читали. Но, сподїваю ся, не дарма повторю ся тут. *Western* зазвичай не використовують для самостійних утворїннь. Якщо ви наумисно навели *the Far West, the West*, то дуже дарма, бо тут він як іменник, а не родовий/прикметник, тобто грубо кажучи на наш лад _Наш Захід_. Тобто в підсумку вони не вкладають сепаратізм в це поняття, а тому хиба порівнювати анґлійське *Western* і українське *Західний*, котре можить бути вживаним і для просто не-іменникового *West*, котре якраз зазвичай сепаратівне.

Comment: @Skill, я поставив питання так, як вважав за потрібне. Дякую.

Answer (score 1):

**[Західна Україна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0)** - це [термін](https://esu.com.ua/article-15884) на означення низки історично українських земель (Галичина, Полісся, Буковина, Волинь, Закарпаття).

Термін [**«Західна Україна»**](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?&I21DBN=EIU&P21DBN=EIU&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=eiu_all&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=TRN=&S21COLORTERMS=0&S21STR=Zakhidna_Ukr_termin) також часто використовують в публіцистиці для спрощення назви **Західноукраїнської Народної Республіки (ЗУНР)**.

В різні історичні періоди цей термін набував різний контекст, а на початку ХХ століття з приходом совєтської влади в Україну, укорінився і до теперішнього часу зберігся в усталеному значенні на позначення територій, де в побуті місцевого населення переважає українська мова й традиція.

[image]

З етнографічної точки зору до західноукраїнських земель відносять такі адміністративні області України: Закарпатська, Львівська, Волинська, Рівненська, Хмельницька, Вінницька, Тернопільська, Івано-Франківська і Чернівецька.

З історико-культурної точки зору Вінницьку область включають до складу [Центральної України](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0).

З точки зору ефективного розподілу ресурсів, з метою балансування, Вінницьку та Житомирську області, разом з Київською та Чернігівською відносять до Північного економічного макрорегіону.

Можливих варіантів для класифікації може існувати безліч, але немає жодної причини у висловах **"Східна Україна"** або **"Західна Україна"** вбачати прояв сепаратизму.

`На заході України`, `на сході України`, `в центральному регіоні України`, `на півночі України`, `на півдні України`, та `в Криму` можна вільно використовувати для зазначення географічного розташування об'єктів на території держави Україна.

Answer (score -1):

На жаль, ви навели однакові приклади вжитку:

- Північна Ірландія є [*[установчою] країною*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B0), хоч і є частиною Злученого королівства. Нескладно здогадатися, що навколо самої назви теж крутяться [суперечки](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_names_for_Northern_Ireland).

  Також варто зазначити, що анґлійська маїть такі структури як *сторона* і *сторона*-*ern*, де  перше зазвичай вживають до самостійних сторін, коли друге — до несамостійних. Звісно, є винятки, але декотрі відомі приклади кажуть самі за себе, наприклад: держава [*South Africa*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Africa) ~ ґеоґрафія [*Southern Africa*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Africa), держава [*East Germany*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Germany) ~ ґеоґрафія [*Eastern Germany*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Germany), держава [*North Macedonia*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Macedonia) ~ ґрецький реґійон [*Western Macedonia*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Macedonia). Вікіпедія змінила друге на *New states of Germany*, але такий вжиток досі є, наприклад в статтї [*Half of eastern Germans 'want authoritarian rule'*](//dw.com/en/half-of-eastern-germans-want-authoritarian-rule/a-66068519) 29 червня цього року від *Deutsche Welle*: «[…] are widespread in *eastern Germany*», що не скасовуїть суперечність такого терміна. Сюди можна додати назву як *Західна Сагара*, що анґлійською [*Western Sahara*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Sahara),  котра є окремою державою де-факто, але не де-юре; тобто це все не дуже підпадаїть під термін як *є частинами назв країни*.

  Тому наводити анґлійські приклади, як декотрі роблять, не дуже доречно, бо українською все це буде зазвичай однаково через прикметник. Хоча якщо геть буквально, то *сторона* це радше іменник, котрий можить ставати прикметником [чи такий собі спрощений родовий без *of*], а *сторона*-*ern* — вже суто прикметник.
- По сутї продовжїння через коментаря [@Yola](/users/9/). Можливо тут і моя біда, що попереднього пункту не вистачило. [*Western United States*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_United_States) позначаїть суто реґійон. Гинші назви як *the Far West, the West* геть не дотичні, бо тут *West* виступаїть в якостї чистого іменника, а не прикметника; до того ж артікль додаїть контекст — розмовник розуміїть про що мова, тобто це не просто абстрактний *далекий схід*, а щось на зразок *наш далекий схід*.

  Якщо дуже хочиться приклади зі Злучених держав Амеріки, хоча тут вони по сутї жодним чином не дотичні, то варто було би також звернути увагу як вжиті сторони для [їхнїх держав](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90), що мають ознаки самостійностї — без наростка *-ern*: *West Virginia*, *North* & *South* до *Carolina*, *Dakota*. Єдиний виняток котрий можна згадати це *Northern Mariana Islands*. Як вже писав, анґлійська відома винятками, але він тут зрозумілий з контексту: щонайменше вони [не держава](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%9E%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B9) в розуміннї ЗДА. Тому за прикладами, скорїш за всього, держава *Західна Україна* будить *West Ukraine*, коли реґійон — *Western Ukraine*, де два терміна однаково будуть через прикметник *західна*.

  Тому повторю ся, **забудьте про анґлійську як приклад до української**. Це геть різні мови, що не дуже дотичні одна до одної, з різним культурним прошарком і [контекстом](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0).
- Терміни *Східна* і *Західна Европа* насамперед є політічними і походять з часів [Холодної війни](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0). Країни, що доїднали ся до Европської унії часто не хочуть позначати себе як *Східні*, тому умовно в румунських підручних можна побачити позначїння Румунії [і Молдови, оскільки це по сутї теж частина Румунії, але котра була під СССР] як [*Центральної Европи*](//redd.it/157do3m), що є відносно новішим терміном. Ґеоґрафія, звісно, мінлива наука, але не настільки, бо маїть бути обґрунтована відповідь на *чому так?*.

Коли кажимо *Західна Україна*, то більшість мають на увазї чи розуміють це як землї, що були частиною держави як [*Західна Україна*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0), навіть попри те, що саме Закарпаття, волосне, західнїше. Про це зазначаїть і [*Енціклопедія сучасної України*](//esu.com.ua/article-15884): «Нині її використовують у 2-х значеннях. Здебільшого так називають лише 3 галиц. області – Львів., Івано-Фр., Терноп., […]». Якщо відоме нам явище з *Східною Нїмеччиною* не дуже очевидне з погляду чистої семантіки, то термін [*Польща А і Б*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%89%D0%B0_%D0%90_%D1%96_%D0%91) вже не такий двозначний і показуїть ту саму сепаратність — в основу лежать гісторічні землї підконтрольні Прусії і Мосвщинї. Так і тут, *Центральна Україна* досить новий термін, до цього землї, що не *Західні*, досї можуть звати ся як *Східні*. Це не єдиний приклад контраста і сепаратностї щодо тих самих дїлянок, наприклад [в свій час](//zbruc.eu/node/91097) звали ся як *Мала* і *Велика України*.

Сучасна політіка досї маїть вплив від тих часів: резултати виборів, наприклад презідента в [1991](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_1991) і [2019](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_2019), [чорна компанія](//chesno.org/political-ads/4136/) команди Януковича (частково) ітд. Тобто загалом такий контекст досї існуїть і непросто його заперечити, тому думки на кшталт якщо хочите указати загалом західну чи якусь дїлянку України радше ґеоґрафічно, а не політічно, то варто перефразувати — цїлком слушна.

Якщо поглянути суто з гісторії і структури мови… [Прикметники](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) мали подїл на *визначені* і *невизначені*, тобто що роблять [втч. відсутністю] анґлійські артіклї. Українська таке давно утратила, пак за основу взяті невизначені, і повернути таке складно. Але польська, що мала вплив [як факт, а не остаточний висновок] на українську, таке досї [маїть, хоча в гиншій формі](https://sjp.pwn.pl/poradnia/haslo/szyk-przymiotnikow;12630.html), котру можна зустрїти і [в українській](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/2528/585), але не в загалому, лише в певних галузях. Це робить ся через прикметник-після-іменника, наприклад науково правильнїше казати не *білий ведмідь*, а [*ведмідь білий*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9). Тобто прикметник, хоч чи не хоч, але таки маїть [і *мав*, але це вже неважливо] таку особливість як виокремлювати, хоч це далеко не його основна дїя.

Можна подумати, що подібну особливість маїть і [родовий відмінок чоловічого роду однини](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8). По перше, зараз вона сприймаїться радше суто як морфолоґічна, тому теж часто є [проблемною](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA). По друге, як на мене, це більше стосуїть ся не визначїння, а злїчїння. В анґлійській це досить [взаїмозалежні теми](//owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/count_and_noncount_nouns/count_noncount_nouns_with_articles_adjectives.html), але не тут. Тож це не дуже граїть ролу тут, пак *Україна* — жіночого роду. Тож родовий зазвичай указуїть на рід, а сам партітів [як в *подай води*, замість очїкуваного *воду*] указуїть як частку від цїлого чогось і радше є частиною згаданої проблеми — *злїчення*. Тому можна зазначити, що родовий хоч теж маїть особливість виокремлювати, але тут вже не як чогось, а радше стану — злїчїння, що не є важливим тут.

Тож такий собі підсумок:

- Контекст і узус досї є. Звісно, його можна не враховувати, що і роблять декотрі. Чи варто так робити? Це вже гинше питаннє, пак вже рівня філософського. Тож, по моєму, це запитаннє вже підпадаїть під флаґ як *opinion-based*, але рїшив відповісти, аби хоча би зазначити на і розглянути поширені помилки і декотрі аспекти, бо таке запитаннє справдї досить популарне.
- Навіть якщо забути про схожі ґеоґрафічні приклади, то прикметник сам по собі таки маїть особливість виокремлювати. Коли родовий — нї.
- Не варто [це не запитнику, але про всяк] наводити приклади з гинших мов, особливо анґлійської, де можуть бути свої особливостї.